# Echo python input or disable input suppression?

Tags: python, input, echo

Is there a way to echo the input in python, or put another way disable the suppression of the input?  I use python for scientific computing, FYI it is useful when debugging to have this functionality.

I have a script window containing code which creates variables, for example `x=1,` on another line i want to type just the variable `x` and get the input i.e. `x` and output i.e. `1` in the shell without having to use `print(x)` (which actually would only give me the value of `x`)

Comment: You need to tell us *how* you get python input (code), what happens and what you expected; your question is currently too vague to answer, I'm afraid.

Comment: What is "input suppression"?  What "input" are you talking about?  The input your program reads from stdin?  Just print it after reading it.

Comment: I have a shell containing code which creates variables, for example x=1, on another line i want to type just the variable x and get the input i.e. x and output i.e. 1 in the command window without having to use print(x) (which actually would only give me the value of x)

Comment: I still don't get it.  What is a "shell" in this context?

Comment: If you use the python shell, you only need to type the variable and press enter.

Comment: Sorry i am having issues with python terminology, when i said command window i meant shell and when i said shell i meant script window, i will edit question

Comment: It sounds to me that @malby would like to see behaviour like Matlab's command window. By running a Matlab script, the user puts its variables into memory. Therefore, inputting a variable name in the shell/command line would provide its value, as described in the question.

Comment: If you run your script from within the python shell you will be able to access all variables from the state where your script finished.

Comment: gary comtois, that is exactly what I would like to do, @MartinFlucka Flucka I am aware that it could be done like this but it makes debugging very messy as it is difficult to track changes and requires constant copying and pasting.

Comment: @malby you do not need to copy your code into the python shell, you can simply import the script.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is opening your file *from* the Python Shell (i.e. IDLE). You can accomplish this through File > Open. This will open your file in a new window. From here you can edit and run your script. Run by navigating to Run > Run Module, or hitting F5. This restarts IDLE and puts makes your variables available from within IDLE.

For example, I typed `a = "weee"` into a .py script (and then ran the script). Now, from my main IDLE window, I typed `a` and got the following output:

```
>>> a
output: 'weee'
```

Comment: Thanks, i did already consider @garycomtois solution, but my issue is subtly different but has many applications for debugging mathematical algoritums quickly.....  I guess there is not a simple solution to this, the only way i have thou8ght about doing this is by including this text in a script print "x =",x which is not ideal as it means i have to type x twice, this may seem like a small detail but actually when working on mathematical algorithms it is really useful to do it very quickly due to the amount of time it takes to debug.

Comment: @malby I'm not sure I understand your comment, or what it is you are looking for... Something more akin to Matlab, right? If you care to get the question reopened, you could start by editing the question to include better description/detail on what you are asking. Best of luck.